# system.runAs() doesn't throw an exception when user doesn't have permission

Tags: unit-test, system.runas

Let's say we have

```
Boolean wasAuraException = false;
system.runAs(TEST_DUMMY_USER) {
            try {
                DataWrapper data = MyController.getData('mockValue');
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                wasAuraException = true;
            } 
            system.assert(wasAuraException, NOT_THROWN_EXCEPTION);
```

in test class.
Definitely, TEST_DUMMY_USER doesn't have a permission to invoke MyController.
Assertion failed with 'NOT_THROWN_EXCEPTION' message
What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected and called out in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_tools_runas.htm).

> The system method runAs enables you to write test methods that change
> the user context to an existing user or a new user so that the user’s
> record sharing is enforced. **The runAs method doesn’t enforce user
> permissions or field-level permissions, only record sharing**.

What would be a valid use case for `runAs` in your situation, if relevant, is asserting that different users get the correct amount of records returned from the method (if sharing dictates this as so).

Use cases of `runAs` in test methods:

- To enforce user's record sharing
- To perform mixed DML operations in your test
- [Testing behavior in package versions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_manpkgs_behavior_testing.htm)